# Remove text lines only from first 2 lines if matches to other column's text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text, nlp

I have a Pandas data frame (Python 3.x) like the following:

| title | type | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mango | Paragraph | Mango is called the king of fruits. It is a stone fruit produced from numerous species of tropical trees..... |
| Dates | Paragraph | [Dates] /n [Paragraph] /n Dates have been a staple food of the Middle East and the Indus Valley for thousands of years...... |
| Mango | Essay | "Mango" "Essay" Mango is called the king of fruits. It is a stone fruit produced from numerous species of tropical trees..... |
| Apple | Article | Apple /n Article /n An apple is an edible fruit produced by an apple tree..... |
| ...... | ...... | ................................................................................... |

In some rows, the text of "title" & "type" column is also present in "content" column. I need to remove the whole line if "title" & "type" is present in the "content" column.
I tried so many times, but failed to remove the whole line containing same text of other columns.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`numpy.char.find`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.find.html):

```
import numpy as np

values = df.values.astype(str)

mask = (np.char.find(values[:,[2,2]], values[:,[0,1]]) == -1).any(1) 
df[mask]
```

**Output**

```
   title       type                                            content
0  Mango  Paragraph  Mango is called the king of fruits. It is a st...
```